# url картинки в img

Tags: javascript, html

В `avatarfull` лежит url картинки.

```
$("#avatar").src(data.avatarfull);
```

Я хочу ее засунуть в `img`

```
<img id="avatar" src="" />
```

В консоли пишет

```
scrypts.js:27 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).src is not a function
    at Object.success (scrypts.js:27)
    at j (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
    at x (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4)
```

Comment: $("#avatar").attr("src",data.avatarfull);

Answer (score 1):

Т.к. у *Jquery* объекта нет функции `src` - он честно об этом и сообщает.

Чтобы поменять атрибут элемента, нужно его так честно  и попросить:

```
$("#avatar").attr("src", data.avatarfull);
```

где **[attr()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8)** - Возвращает или изменяет значение атрибутов у выбранных элементов страницы. То есть может быть геттером или сеттером